# Bootstrap typeahead prefetch functionality

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

So I am using the Bootstraps typeahead API to create a live search.

The source parameter is great, because it allows to use the AJAX call to get the data from the server. However I would like to be able to 'prefetch' the source when the page loads, and only execute the ajax call if there are no matches in the 'prefetched' data.

How could I make this possible? My ajax call is here:

```
    $("#topsearchbar").typeahead({
        items: 8,
        source: function (query, process) {
            $.get( "/topsearchbar", {"data":query}, function(data) {
                process( data );
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is how I did it in the end:

```
var Obj = {};
var Arr = [];
var preFetchResult = function (query, callback) {
    $.get( "/request", {"data":query}, function(data) {
        Obj = {};
        Arr = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            Arr.push( data[i].name );
            Obj[ data[i].id ] = data[i].name;
        }
        callback(Obj,Arr);
    });
};

$(window).load(function() {
    preFetchResult("", function(obj,arr) { // Empty query prefetches all db data
        $("#bar").typeahead({
            items: 8,
            source: function (query, process) {
                process(arr);
                $.get("/request", {"data":query}, function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                        if (obj[data.results[i].id] === undefined) {
                            obj[data.results[i].id] = data.results[i].name;
                            arr.push(data.results[i].name);
                        }
                    }
                    process(arr);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you actually want is to cache data already fetched.

```
var query_data = {};
$("#topsearchbar").typeahead({
    items: 8,
    source: function (query, process) {
        if (query_data[query] === undefined) {
            $.get( "/topsearchbar", {"data":query}, function(data) {
                query_data[query] = data;
                process( data );
            });
        } else {
            process(query_data[query]);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, I actually wanted to prefetch data, however to do it with an ajax request. I solved it, watch my answer if you are interested :)

Comment: Ps. Thanks for the tip to use objects in this case